# Using the comma operator in if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, comma-operator

I tried the following:

```
if(int i=6+4==10)
    cout << "works!" << i;

if(int i=6+4,i==10)
    cout << "doesn't even compile" << i;
```

The first works fine while the second doesn't compile. Why is this?

EDIT: Now I know that the first one may not work as I intend it to. The value of i inside the if scope will be 1, not 10. (as pointed out by one of the comments on this question).

So is there a way to initialize and use a variable inside of an if statement at the same time similar to `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`? So that you could produce something like `if((int i=6+4)==10)` (which will not compile) where the value of I inside the if scope would be 10?
I know you could declare and initialize I before the if statement but is there a way to do this within the statement itself?

To give you an idea why I think this would be usefull.

```
 if(int v1=someObject1.getValue(), int v2=someObject2.getValue(), v1!=v2)
    {
        //v1 and v2 are visible in this scope 
        //and can be used for further calculation without the need to call
        //someObject1.getValue() und someObject2.getValue() again.
    }
    //if v1==v2 there is nothing to be done which is why v1 und v2
    //only need to be visible in the scope of the if.
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Any specific requirement?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Neither of them should compile... Edit: Statement retracted.

Comment: I would guess that you don't know what the comma operator actually does. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @quasiverse: The first is OK (read it as `int i = (6 + 4 == 10)`)

Comment: @AlexandreC. Wait... holy... o.O you can do that?... Well, guess you learn something new every day.

Comment: @quasiverse: `=` binds less tightly than any other operator.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I knew all that, I just didn't know you could declare in `if` statements.

Comment: `=` in this code is not the assignment operator, it is introducing an initializer for `i`.

Comment: to Nawaz: There is no specific requirement. I just want to get a better feeling for c++. 
@tenfour I believe it executes all arguments but only return the value of the last one. Essentialy I want it to behave just like the first one. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @BorisMonth: The first one may not work as you intend it to. The value of `i` inside the `if` scope will be `1`, not `10`.

Comment: @BorisMonth: If you want to *get a better feeling for c++*, you should try idiomatic code, rather than pushing the syntax in ways that it is rarely used. I do use declarations in `if` statements when dealing with C interfaces: `if ( int rc = operation() ) { // error }`, but that is almost the only case where I have seen a declaration in an `if`...

Comment: @AlexandreC. Thanks. You're right. So I should have asked for if((int i=6+4)==10) which will not compile either... So maybe I should just accept that you can't declare, initialize and use a variable inside of an if statement at the same time. 
The reason I asked the question is: for(int i=0;i<10;i++) works ^^

Comment: Don't you think it might be better if you learn the language first before you start trying to hack the grammar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression used as an initializer expression must be an *assignment-expression* so if you want to use a comma operator you must parenthesize the initializer.

E.g. (not that what you are attempting makes much sense as `6 + 4` has no side effects and the value is discarded and `i == 10` uses the uninitialized value of `i` in its own initializer.)

```
if (int i = (6 + 4, i == 10)) // behaviour is undefined
```

Did you really mean something like this?

```
int i = 6 + 4;
if (i == 10)
```

When using the form of `if` that declares a new variable the condition checked is always the value of the initialized variable converted to `bool`. If you want the condition to be an expression involving the new variable you must declare the variable before the `if` statement and use the expression that you want to test as the condition.

E.g.

```
int i;
if ((i = 6 + 4) == 10)
```

Comment: That is different than what the question has, and it would also be undefined (the value of `i` before the comparison is undefined.

Comment: I don't understand your `if` statement - you are assigning `i` to a `bool` and comparing `i` before it's initialized. What's the point, it's not the same as the OP.

Comment: @Dave: it doesn't make sense; the question asked how to use the coma operator and I tried to make the simplest "fix" to the second example to make it syntactically valid (`bool` will promote to an `int`.) I am unclear as to the actual intent of the original code.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt seriously either example *works* to do anything useful.  All that it does is evaluate to "true" in a complicated fashions.

But the reason the second one doesn't compile is that  it's interpreted as two declarations: `int i = 6+4; int i==10` and `int i==10` isn't valid because that's an equality operator, not an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

There are different alternatives, because what you want cannot be done (you cannot mix the comma operator with declarations). You could, for example, declare the variable outside of the `if` condition:

```
int i = 6+4;
if ( i == 10 ) ...
```

Or you can change the value of `i` to be `0` instead of `10` and recalculate `i` inside the `else` block:

```
if ( int i = (6+4)-10 ) ; else {
   i += 10;
   // ...
}
```

Much simpler, don't declare the variable at all, since you know the value inside the loop:

```
if ( (6+4)==10 ) {
   int i = 10;
   // ...
}
```

Unless of course you need the value of `i` in the case where it is not `10`, in which case the second option is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As of C++17 what you were trying to do [is finally possible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```
if (int i=6+4; i==10)
    cout << "works, and i is " << i << endl;
```

Note the use of `;` of instead of `,` to separate the declaration and the actual condition.